# Comportamiento indefinido en implementación de vector

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy leyendo el libro de Bjarne Stroustrup "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ 2nd".
Actualmente me encuentro en la página 706 del capítulo 19. A grandes rasgos el capítulo habla sobre las garantías de excepción y la programación genérica, poniendo como ejemplo la implementación de un vector como el de la STL.  El código reducido y funcional es este:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename A>
struct vector_base {
    A alloc;
    vector_base(const vector_base &) {
        std::cout << "vector_base contructor copia\n";
    }
    vector_base &operator=(const vector_base &) {
        std::cout << "vector_base operator=\n";
        return *this;
    }
    vector_base(vector_base &&) {
        std::cout << "vector_base contructor movimiento\n";
    }
    vector_base &operator=(vector_base &&) {
        std::cout << "vector_base operator=&&\n";
        return *this;
    }
    T* elem;
    int sz, capacit;
    vector_base(const A& a, size_t n) : alloc(a), elem(alloc.allocate(n)), sz(n), capacit(n) {}
    ~vector_base() {
        alloc.deallocate(elem,capacit);
    }
};

template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
class vector : private vector_base<T,A> {
    public:
        size_t size() const { return this->sz; }
        size_t capacity() const { return this->capacit; }
        vector() : vector_base<T, A>{A{},0} {}
        void reserve(size_t newalloc) {
            if(newalloc <= this->capacit)
                return;
            vector_base<T,A> b(this->alloc,newalloc); // <-1
            std::uninitialized_copy(b.elem,&b.elem[this->sz],this->elem); // <-2
            for(size_t i = 0; i< this->sz; i++) {
                this->alloc.destroy(&this->elem[i]);
            }
            std::swap<vector_base<T,A>>(*this,b); // <-3
        }
        void push_back(const T& val ) {
            if (this->capacit == 0)
                reserve(8);
            else if(this->capacit == this->sz)
                reserve(this->capacit*2);
            this->alloc.construct(&this->elem[this->sz],val);
            this->sz++;
        }
};

void info(const vector<double>& vec) {

    std::cout << "size: " << vec.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "capcity: " << vec.capacity() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    vector<double> v;
    info(v);
    v.reserve(3);
    info(v);
    v.push_back(3);
    info(v);
}
```

Tengo 3 preguntas acerca del código, están marcadas con **// <-nº**

1. ¿No necesitaríamos otro constructor para vector_base que no cambie el valor de sz? reserve() no se ocupa de sz solo de capacit.
2. ¿Qué sentido tiene que el resultado de uninitialized_copy sea elem y no b.elem? y además, ¿esto no provoca un acceso fuera de los límites del vector si se usa todo el espacio reservado?
3. ¿Por qué se llama al contructor/operador de movimiento en lugar de llamar a los de copia?

Comment: En referencia a la pregunta 2 mira esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885985/stroustrup-c-implementation-of-reserve. Parece que hay un error en el código del libro.